# Annotate method with name of another method should be clickable

Tags: java, annotations, intellisense

I have a class Animal 
It has two constructors default and parameterised. Now I want to annotate default constructor so that the developer will know that this method should be avoided instead parameterised one should be used.

```
class Animal
{

/**
Discouraged- Use Animal(String name) instead.
*/
public Animal()
{}


public Animal(String name)
{...}

}
```

Here i have annotated default constructor but intellisense does not highlight/clickable the param constructor name in the intellisense block.

Also please share a document if you have, where all "@" annotations are defined in a simple understandable format.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `Deprecated` annotation and Javadoc to explain why.

```
class Animal
{

/**
 * @deprecated
 * please don't use this method anymore
 */
@Deprecated
public Animal()
{}


public Animal(String name)
{...}

}
```

With this annotation, the compiler will show an warning to don't use that method.

Maybe this site helps you.

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

I hope this information helps you.

Good Luck.